# jQuery .attr code to work in Drupal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drupal

Check out my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KevinOrin/zuFae/

The code successfully works there but not on the Drupal site I am coding it for: http://gossiptalk.info/users/gossiptalk

I copied out the html directly from the Drupal DOM output and no matter where I put the js it doesn't work. And yes it's loading the jQuery library. Any thoughts?

```
$(document).on("click", function () {
var _href = $("#map-addr").attr("href");
var _addr = $("#map-addr div.field-item").text();
$("#map-addr").attr("href", _href + _addr);
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe drupal uses [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) therefore the `$` will no longer reference the jQuery object. Just use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

```
jQuery(document).on("click", function () {
    var _href = jQuery("#map-addr").attr("href");
    var _addr = jQuery("#map-addr div.field-item").text();
    jQuery("#map-addr").attr("href", _href + _addr);
});
```

Comment: Thanks,Tried that and still nothing. If you inspect the address element you will see the script right below it. Could the placement be an issue?

Comment: @KevinOrin you have to replace all not just the first one.

Comment: Got it, that works thanks. The event loops and repeats the link but I can fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this and still write jQuery like you're used to inside it, since it makes the $ local to itself and outputs to jQuery. It generally works the same as document.ready

```
(function($){
    $(document).on("click", function () {
        var _href = $("#map-addr").attr("href");
        var _addr = $("#map-addr div.field-item").text();
        $("#map-addr").attr("href", _href + _addr);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: the ending syntax is a bit off

Comment: updated to reflect the line that didn't make it into your code block.

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if there are any errors? Also, what browser are you seeing the issues in?

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use the 'jQuery' variable instead of the $ variable in your code.

See: http://drupal.org/node/171213

http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#javascript_compatibility

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
jq(document).on("click", function () {
  var _href = jq("#map-addr").attr("href");
  var _addr = jq("#map-addr div.field-item").text();
  jq("#map-addr").attr("href", _href + _addr);
});
```